# how to verify order of elements in a list or array

Tags: php, sorting

ETA: I'm thinking that my question needs some clarification. I don't want to sort my arrays. I want to be sure that a given array that is in order by a particular criterion, is also in order by another criterion.  I made a graphic to illustrate. Each row is an array ordered by number. If the letters are also in order, the array passes the test.

[image]

---

## Original Question

I have a parent class PhysicalCount with 2 properties: `date`, `count`. I also have subclasses of PhysicalCount: `ClutchCount`, `FryCount` and `MatCount`.  When I have a mixed array of PhysicalCounts and subclasses I need to verify (not set!) that the order matches these criteria:

1. objects are in order by `date`
2. 0 to 1 objects of each child class may exist
3. 0 to many objects of `PhysicalCount` may exist
4. if a `ClutchCount` is present it must have an earlier date than a `FryCount` or `MatCount` if those exist
5. if a `FryCount` is present it must have an earlier date than a `MatCount` if that exists

Boiled down, the question is something like:

Given a list sorted by one criterion (`$o->date` in my case), what is the most efficient way to ascertain that sorting that same list by another criterion (`get_class($o)`in my case) will result in the same order?

I'd prefer a solution in PHP, but I'm thinking this is a fairly common problem that has a standard solution that I just don't know the name of. (Here is me regretting my degree choice [not CS]).

Comment: If it is given that the list is sorted by date, why do you need to verify that they are sorted by date?

Comment: As far as item 3, it is always the case that 0 to many objects of `PhysicalCount` exist, unless you can have a negative number of objects.

Comment: @Yoel- how would you phrase it to mean that there can be as many un-subclassed objects as desired?

Comment: @dnagirl sorry if I was unclear, what I am trying to say is that there is no need to check for the number of "un-subclassed" objects because that test would always be true (assuming that you can have any number, 0 or many)

Comment: @yoel: the reason I put that criterion in was to make it clear that ClutchCount, FryCount and MatCount could be interspersed with any number of generic objects. It's not a required condition; it's a difficulty that makes the problem harder for me to solve.

Comment: @dnagirl sorry I guess I misunderstood what you were asking. Moving on to the "boiled down" description of the problem, if all you need to know is if an array sorted in two different ways has the same ordering, why dont you just scan the two arrays simultaneously and check each item for equivalence?

Comment: @yoel: mainly because of the interspersed generic objects. When I sort by class, all the generics will clump together (and that's ok). I need to be sure that the subclasses are still in date order when they are sorted by class.

Answer (score 1):

Based on our discussion in the comments, what you need is a sort that is somewhat "stable" (not actually a stable sort by definition though) use [usort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#38827) to sort the objects in the array in a user-defined way. You can specify in your `$cmp_function` the criteria you mentioned in your question, so that the sorted array fits your needs.